# How to order products by custom taxonomies in Woocommerce?

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I have searching for a long time to find a solution to my problem, but it seems I can't find it (or maybe I don't understand well some posts I have found here).

The thing is that I have create a custom tag on my site, which is "marca" (label, in English). My client wants to sort all her products by this tag ("marca") and in alphabetical order too. But Woocommerce, by default, sorts the products by title, date, price... you know, but if I want to customize a sorting it's very difficult.

I have tried some codes from this forum, but unfortunately they don't work at all. Is it possible to do this trick?

Thank you.

Comment: what code are you using actually to accomplish the sorting?

Comment: What you need is a taxonomy query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: @jjj I've tried various codes but with no success. I think I'm doing something wrong. For example, from this threat:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163255/woocommerce-order-by-custom-taxonomy

Or this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937078/order-by-custom-woocommerce-product-sorting-in-a-wp-query

I'm using Code Snippets plugin to introduce the code (not int functions.php).

Comment: @DanielVisser Thank you, but I'm lost with that kind of information. I know too little of code, so I don't understand well... sorry. So, I'm asking for help if someone could tell me how to make this happens :(

Comment: I posted my answer with an example.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: Hello again, @DanielVisser and first of all thank you very much for your help and sorry for the delay on my answer.
I've tried your code, but nothing happens :(
I'm wondering if it's caused by my theme (OceanWP) or by Elementor (I've built the catalog page using Elementor). Both theme and constructor have their own query options, and maybe these options are over any other change I try to do...
Anyway, take a look at this capture:
http://i66.tinypic.com/34yzb6b.jpg
At the bottom of the image you can see the url generated when I put the mouse over the "marca" tag. It's ok with your code?

Comment: Ahhh i see now, your  taxonomy is called 'marca', i will update my answer.

Comment: I updated my anwser, it should work now.

Comment: @DanielVisser There is no change with your update :( I think OceanWP or Elementor is interfering the code. Look at the options from OceanWP first:
http://i66.tinypic.com/k4za5f.jpg
(in English: personalized+name; popularity; valoración... mmm sorry, I don't remember; order by date; by price asc; by price desc).
And now the options from Elementor:
http://es.tinypic.com/m/k0fw9u/3
And if you choose manual selection:
http://i64.tinypic.com/ebafjl.jpg
It should work with personalized option, but no.
I'm adding the code with Code Snippets, I must remember, I don't know if this is important.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, by the way.

Comment: You can’t just copy the code and paste it in a snippet, it won’t work. I thought you were filtering a query or editing layout files. I wil try to find a hook for you so we can make this work. Can you give me the url of the page where the products with tag ‘marca’ should be displayed?

Comment: @DanielVisser unfortunately the site is still in development mode, so it's closed to the public :( Maybe I can give you access with a very limited user options. Do you need only to see the site?
Again, thank you for your interest and help :)

Comment: It does not matter, i only need the url. You can even block out the domain name. I need to know which page it is.

Comment: This is the url: http://www.jugueteseducativosonline.com (but it is in maintenance mode, I wanted to say before).

Comment: Do you have the pro version of elementor? And can you set a query id in the query tab?

Comment: @DanielVisser Yes, I work with Elementor Pro. And to the other question, no I can't, what you see in the capture is what you get when editing the archive product widget.

Comment: Hi @DaniëlVisser The site is online now. Can you take a look, please? https://ladidacteca.es Thanks!

Comment: On what page do you want the products ordered? Then i can see if i can help.

Comment: Hello. My client wants to show that sorting at the archive (or catalog) page. She wants to show her products alphabetically as well as by "marca" (because she wants to group them this way). As you can see, now you can order by default (alphabetically), popularity, recent products and price.

Comment: Updated my anwser check below ***EDIT:***.

Comment: Hi, @DaniëlVisser Sorry for the late answer (I've been out for the weekend). Unfortunately it didn't work. I think it's because the sorting comes from the Theme (OceanWP), and it doesn't allow to add any other order setup. I give up. I'll tell my client is not possible to do what she wants because some restrictions or something like this.
Of course, thank you very much for your help, my friend. It's a pleasure to find good people that try to help ;)

Comment: Maybe @LoicTheAztec could help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a WP_Query example with explanations for you, it returns posts of type 'product' with the taxonomy 'marca' that have terms set in an alphabetical order.

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product', // The post type we want to query, in our case 'product'.
    'orderby' => 'title',     // Return the posts in an alphabetical order.
    'order' => 'ASC',         // Return the posts in an ascending order.
    'posts_per_page' => -1,   // How many post we want to return per page, -1 stands for no limit.
    'tax_query' => array(     // Taxonomy query
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'marca',  // The taxonomy we want to query, in our case 'marca'.
            'operator' => 'EXISTS'  // Return the post if it has the selected taxonomy with terms set, in our case 'marca'.
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
if( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo the_title();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
And here is the code you can paste in a code snippet. It hooks `woocommerce_product_query` and alters the query on all archive pages.

```
function custom_woocommerce_product_query( $query ){

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' ); // Return the posts in an alphabetical order.
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' ); // Return the posts in an ascending order.

    $tax_query = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'marca',  // The taxonomy we want to query, in our case 'marca'.
        'operator' => 'EXISTS'  // Return the post if it has the selected taxonomy with terms set, in our case 'marca'.
    );
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_woocommerce_product_query', 10, 1 );
```